# Non-linear regression analysis in R

Tags: r, regression, non-linear-regression

I'm a R novice but I'm looking for a way to determine the three parameters A, B and C related by the following function in R:

`y = A * (x1^B) * (x2^C)`

Can someone give me some hints about R method(s) that would help me to achieve such a fitting?

Comment: What is the error distribution that you can assume? i.e. is it normal, log-normal, Cauchy, etc. etc.? Are errors in different observations correlated with each other? While `nls` **may** fit your bill, it may also give you biased and inefficient estimates. Without the error model, you're literally groping in the dark.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is the `nls` function as @SvenHohenstein suggested.  Another option is to convert your nonlinear regression into a linear regression.  In the case of this equation just take the log of both sides of the equation and do a little algebra and you will have a linear equation.  You can run the regression using something like:

```
fit <- lm( log(y) ~ log(x1) + log(x2), data=mydata)
```

The intercept will be `log(A)` so use `exp` to get the value, the B and C parameters will be the 2 slopes.

The big difference here is that `nls` will fit the model with normal errors added to the original equation and the `lm` fit with logs assumes that the errors in the original model are from a lognormal distribution and are multiplied instead of added to the model.  Many datasets will give similar results for the 2 methods.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to get an estimate of the parameter B since x1 is a constant in my model. I'm always getting: Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)

Comment: @Yann, if x1 is constant then you could either leave it out in the 'lm' case, or use `offset` to include it with a B value of 1 (or other prespecified value).

Answer (score 5):

You can fit a nonlinear least-squares model with the function `nls`.

```
nls(y ~ A * (x1^B) * (x2^C))
```

Comment: And if this should happen to be homework, beware the perfect dataset. As per `?nls` , it won't converge unless there's noise in the data.

Comment: Maybe I should mention that my x1 is a constant and therefore always get this error: singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates

Comment: @Yann I suppose two vectors (i.e., `y` and `x2`) are insufficient for estimating three parameters. You might wish to consider using a simpler model.

Answer (score -1):

Why don´t you use SVM (Suppor Vector Machines) Regression? there´s a package in CRAN named `e1071` that can handle regression with SVM.

You can check this tutorial: http://www.svm-tutorial.com/2014/10/support-vector-regression-r/

I hope it can help you